# Heroku/SQLAlchemy: requirements.txt local does not get uploaded to heroku remote

Tags: flask, heroku, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, requirements.txt

**Local pip list is as follows**

[image]

**Heroku pip list is as follows**

[image]

[image]

Error shows up since SQLAlchemy/FlaskSQLAlchemy both/any of the 2 never get installed on heroku.

Manual install using "heroku run pip install Flask-SQLAlchemy" or any other install says its complete but actually does not happen.

Manually appending text to the requirements.txt on heroku file does not work as well since it does not add the text to the file although no error is thrown on execution of the command.

Comment: How does your `requirements.txt` look in your project?

Comment: appdirs==1.4.4
cachelib==0.1.1
certifi==2021.5.30
click==8.0.1
colorama==0.4.4
distlib==0.3.2
filelock==3.0.12
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-Session==0.3.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1
greenlet==1.1.0
itsdangerous==2.0.1
Jinja2==3.0.1
MarkupSafe==2.0.1
pipenv==2021.5.29
six==1.16.0
SQLAlchemy==1.4.17
virtualenv==20.4.7
virtualenv-clone==0.5.4
Werkzeug==2.0.1
WTForms==2.3.3

Comment: each of the above on a single line

Comment: Are you sure that `pip list` shows the installed modules of your deployed application? A lot more of your `requirements.txt` is missing... if you deploy your app on heroku do you get any errors regarding the installation of the modules above?

Comment: no it does not show any errors and if I manually install them it shows ans installed but if I check post installation it says not present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a fix:
Need to add sqlalchemy and other packages in Pipfile

**Pipfile Before**

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[packages]
flask = "*"
gunicorn = "*"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.9.5"
```

**Pipfile After**

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[packages]
flask = "*"
gunicorn = "*"
sqlalchemy = "*"
flask-sqlalchemy = "*"
wtforms = "*"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.9.5"
```

Then run

```
pipenv lock
```

Commit and push changes, then check requirements.txt on heroku you will notice sqlalchemy is present in it